# Is there a simple way to update location to all partitions in hive external table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I create some dataframe with spark daily, and save it to HDFS location.
Before saving I partition data by some fields, so path to data looks like this:

```
/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/table_name/...
```

table_name directory has partitions like:

```
table_name/field=value1
table_name/field=value2
```

I create external table to operate the data with Hive and set location to data path.

Each day I want to change location to new data path. But if I use

```
ALTER TABLE table 
SET LOCATION 'new location'
```

querying still return old data because partition's locations don't change.

Is there any way to tell Hive to search partitions in new location, without changing it one by one?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep the old partition you can drop using the below command and try to add a clause that matches all partition

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (field != 'non_exist_value');
```

Then you can check the remaining partition again using the below command

```
SHOW PARTITIONS table_name;
```

After that, you can change it to a new location and repair the hive table to create a new partition under the new location (The partition column name in new location must be the same as old)

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET LOCATION '/new_location';

MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```